# Resize persistent disk of Google Cloud VM: Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock

Tags: virtual-machines, ubuntu-14.04, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to follow the [official Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd) on how to resize the persistent disk of a Compute Engine image.

According to the instructions, after I determine the new disk size in the Web Console I need to run `resize2fs` to resize the filesystem to the new disk space. However, when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
resize2fs: Device or resource busy while trying to open /dev/disk/by-id/google-[my-disk-id]
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I just had to restart the instance and it was automatically resized. This behavior was [mentioned](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/create-root-persistent-disks#repartitionrootpd) in another point of the documentation:

> If you create or resize a root persistent disk or create a disk from an image or a snapshot, your virtual machine instance can automatically resize the partition to recognize the additional space after you restart the instance.

Answer (score 1):

Just reboot the system to using

```
$ sudo reboot
```

will resolve this issue